# Concordance de temps pour un conditionnel dans le futur

Tags: temps-grammatical, conditionnel

J’ai trouvé [sur EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68672/what-does-every-jewish-mother-will-die-a-fact-many-are-not-exactly-famous-for) une construction intéressante en anglais:

> One day I'll be dead, then you'll wish you could pay me a visit!

Doit-on utiliser dans les propositions subordonnées le futur antérieur et le subjonctif plus-que-parfait pour obtenir une pareille signification en français?

Voici ma tentative d'interprétation en français:

> Un jour je serai mort, alors tu auras voulu que tu m'eusses visité.

Je vous remercie beaucoup de me faire parvenir votre opinion.

Comment: @Stéphane Gimenez, merci beacoup pour l’edit, une qualité remarquable.

Comment: Quelques pistes pour te corriger : 1) "tu auras voulu" exprime un passé (je ne crois pas que c'est ce que tu veuilles.)  2) Le verbe qui suit "vouloir" doit se mettre à l'infinitif (si le sujet reste le même). 3) "Vouloir" n'est dans ce cas peut-être pas la meilleure traduction de *wish*. 4) en français on "visite" un lieu, mais on "rend visite" à quelqu'un.

Comment: @Laure, j’apprécie très bien votre précieuses informations, merci beacoup.

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour toutes réponses!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lorsque le temps et le sujet de l'action sont les même que le moment de la modalité, on utilise l'infinitif.

> Un jour, je serai morte, et alors tu souhaiteras pouvoir me rendre visite.

La phrase en anglais a une nuance supplémentaire : « *wish you could* », avec le conditionnel, implique que l'action souhaitée est impossible. Je pense que le meilleur moyen de rendre cette nuance est de changer le verbe en un verbe négatif.

> Un jour, je serai morte, et alors tu regretteras ne pas pouvoir me rendre visite.
>   Un jour, je serai morte, et alors tu regretteras ne plus pouvoir me rendre visite.

Si l'action de la visite était dans le passé par rapport à la modalité, mais le sujet était le même, on utiliserait l'infinitif passé. Attention, ce n'est pas ce qu'exprime la phrase anglaise — vu ta propositon de traduction, je pense que tu as fait un contresens.

> Un jour, je serai morte, et alors tu souhaiteras avoir pu me rendre visite.
>   Un jour, je serai morte, et alors tu regretteras de n'avoir pas pu me rendre visite.

Si le sujet est différent, on utilise le subjonctif.

> Un jour, je serai morte, et alors tu souhaiteras qu'elle puisse me rendre visite.
>   Un jour, je serai morte, et alors tu souhaiteras qu'elle ait pu me rendre visite.
>   Un jour, je serai morte, et alors tu regretteras qu'elle n'ait pas pu me rendre visite.

Pas de subjonctif plus-que-parfait ici, puisque le temps principal n'est pas au passé.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer is astonishing, a piece (sample) of French at its very best!

Answer (score 2):

Je n'utiliserait pas *vouloir*, mais *souhaiter* comme pseudo auxiliaire ici:

> Un jour je serai mort(e), alors tu souhaiteras m'avoir rendu visite.
>
> Lorsque je serai mort(e), tu souhaiteras m'avoir rendu visite.

La dernière partie de la phrase serait peut-être encore mieux rendue pour l'effet culpabilisant par quelque chose du genre *tu souhaiteras m'avoir vu(e) une dernière fois.*

Comment: “Un jour je serai morte, tu souhaiteras m’avoir rendu visite” est bizarre, tout de même. J’ajouterai une conjonction ou je transformerai la première partie en subordonnée.

Comment: En effet. Je n'ai pas fait attention en ajoutant l'option pour "lorsque".

Comment: Attention, cette phrase en français est correcte et idiomatique, mais elle ne traduit pas la phrase anglaise (en anglais, on dirait « … *wish you **could have paid** me a visit* »).

Answer (score -1):

je peux interpréter ça comme ça

« Un jour je serai mort, puis vous allez souhaiter que vous pouvez me rendre visite! ».

Comment: J’ai voté -1 parce que la phrase proposée n’est pas correcte. Je n’utiliserais pas aller + *infinitif*, qui sert plutôt à exprimer un futur proche ; j’utiliserais un subjonctif pour *pouvoir* ; le puis semble illogique dans la phrase. Et même avec ces corrections, la phrase me semblerait médiocre.